# Why I can't access the properties json data by the property name in reactjs?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to get data from database using mongodb and mongoose.

i have a request function:

```
componentDidMount(){

        fetch('http://localhost:5000/tweet')
        .then(function(response) {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(result=>{
            this.setState({
                tweetData:JSON.stringify(result)
            });
            console.log(this.state.tweetData);
        });

    }
```

I'm try show by console.log, it's ok:

[image]
but when i access the properties by property name the console.log show: null

why?

here is my backend code:

```
app.get('/tweet',(req,res)=>{
    tweetData.find((err,data)=>{
        if(err){
            return res.json({success: false, error: err});
        }
        return res.json({success: true, data:data});
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are parsing the JSON and then stringifying it again. Remove `JSON.stringify` and it should work as expected.

`setState` is also asynchronous, so you can't access the new state in the statement below it. You can use the second argument of `setState` which is a callback that will be called when the state has been set.

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/tweet')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => {
            this.setState({
                tweetData: result
            }, () => console.log(this.state.tweetData));
        })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to `result.data`.

```
.then(result=>{
        this.setState({
            tweetData:result.data
        },()=>{
            console.log(this.state.tweetData);
        );

    });
```

And `setState` is async you can use callback function to check state update